# XPages: Single Page Application Data View refresh

Tags: xpages

I have a Single Page Application that has two pages - the first page contains a Data View view control (I used the wizard to create the pages - I did not create any custom controls as the entire application only contains 4 pages!), the second page then displays the document selected in the Data View control. This works perfectly! My problem is that the documents that are displayed in the Data View Control are not being refreshed - I need to do a manual refresh for them to show up. Not a problem I though, just do an automatic refresh every 5 seconds (there are only going to be about 20 users using the application):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL="></meta>
```

this refreshes the page perfectly - if a user is on the second page s/he gets bumped back to the page with the Data View control (i.e. Page 1) and does not stay on the open document (ie page 2).

How can I get the Data View control to refresh periodically without being bumped back to the Data View control?

Thanking you in advance
ursus

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really want to refresh the view every n seconds as that has the possibility of becoming a huge performance issue, plus the cause for weirdness as you pointed out. There are 2 ways to approach this:

- In the Application Page properties, set resetContent to true
- Create a onAfterTransitionIn event to do an XSP.partialRefreshGet on the data view or it's container. This way when someone lands on the view it'll refresh it's contents. Below is an example:

  ```
  var widget = dijit.byId("#appPageName");
  dojo.connect(widget, "onAfterTransitionIn", function(moveTo, dir, transition, context, method){
      console.log("onAfterTransitionIn args=",arguments);
      var appPageChildren = dojo.query("[id='" + appPageName + "']").children()[0];
      var contentId = appPageChildren.id;
      console.log("contentId=",contentId);
      setTimeout(function() {
          XSP.partialRefreshGet(contentId, {});
      },200);
  });
  ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I had already tried resetContent -> this does not do anything in this context as far as I can see - it definitely does not refresh the view when new documents are added by the backend. . Thank you for your code but that is not what I am looking for. "All" I really want is the view (Data View Control) to refresh when new documents get added to it by eg. another user.

Comment: The modern way to approach this is to look at Facebook or Google+. When new content is available you are notified at which point you can choose to refresh to see the new content. However, with an nsf there is no mechanism present to do this (at least that is able to be surfaced in xsp). So, I would approach this by a) updating the content when someone lands on the view and/or b) provide "pull to refresh" functionality for the view. I say this because if the application grows past your few users, auto updating will become a performance bottleneck and detract from the user experience.

Comment: Hi. I do understand what you are saying and that would be a good approach for office workers. This application is being used in production by forklift drivers. Making the user refresh the view means that s/he would need to stop, take their hands off the steering wheel and refresh the view. This is OK if they are going to interact with the application anyway (to accept the next production order which is what they do on page 2) but not just to see if there is an order for them :o( I am currently thinking of having 2 pages, one with an auto refresh and one to accept the order.